# How Extract columns to free command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I execute the command `free -mo` in linux and my output is:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         64401      33265      31135          0        667      15455
Swap:         4099          0       4099
```

But i need the output:

```
             total       used       free
Mem:         64401      33265      31135
Swap:         4099          0       4099
```

I intended to use `free -mo | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}'` but my result is:

```
total used free shared
Mem: 64401 33268 31132
Swap: 4099 0 4099
```

I appreciate your help .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
free -mo |
awk '{print (NR==1?"Type":""), $1, $2, $3, (NR==1?"":$4)}' |
column -t
```

- `Added a column`Type` for make first row a consists of 4 column
- `column -t` is for tabular formatting

**Output:**

```
Type   total  used  free
Mem:   2003   163   1840
Swap:  1430   0     1430
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: FYI `awk '{print (NR>1?"":"Total"),$1,$2,$3,$4}'` would produce the same output after the pipe to `column -t`.

Comment: Thanks so much Ed, I should have thought about that.

Answer (score 1):

Preserving right aligned numbers:

```
free -mo | awk 'BEGIN{len=0} NR==1{len=length(gensub(/free.*$/, "free",1))} {print substr($0,1,len)}'
             total       used       free
Mem:          7913       7377        535
Swap:         8115        569       7546
```

Answer (score 1):

another `awk` without filler header

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==1{print "",$1,$2,$3;next} {print $1,$2,$3,$4}' file

        total   used    free
Mem:    64401   33265   31135
Swap:   4099    0       4099
```